# Scope variables in typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I'm working with Angular 2 (Typescript) on Ionic 2 App. I have one class `NewFavoriteSitePage` with private property `siteForm` and I can use this property in class methods but when I am inside one google maps method this variable is undefined. What are the scope of variable or How do I define the variable to access from both sides?

```
declare var google;
......
export class NewFavoriteSitePage {
  .....
  private siteForm: FormGroup;

  loadMap(){
  //I can access to siteForm here!
  .....
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(marker, siteForm){
        let newlatLng = marker.latLng; 
        console.log(this.siteForm); //Here this.siteForm is undefined
      });
  }
```

Comment: I'm testing with `public siteForm: FormGroup` but it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm testing with `declare var siteForm: any` below `declare var google` and doesn't work too.

Comment: this doesn't have anything to do with typescript or what type you use. You are creating a function with it's own new `this` that has nothing to do with the class itself. Use an arrow function, bind, closing over `var that = this` or one of the countless other ways to make sure `this` in the new function is what you want it to be.

Answer (score 3):

the reason why google maps is not defined there, is because it is the callback of a function, which makes 'this' not equal to the page anymore, putting it in a variable will fix the issue.

```
  private siteForm: FormGroup;

  loadMap(){
  var siteformFromPage=this.siteForm; //this should work
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(marker, siteForm){
        let newlatLng = marker.latLng; 
        console.log(siteformFromPage);
      });
  }
```

EDIT: if you want the latest value, you could also try is this way:

```
  private siteForm: FormGroup;

  loadMap(){
       var that=this; //cache that value of the page.

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(marker, siteForm){
        let newlatLng = marker.latLng; 
        console.log(that.siteformFromPage);
      });
  }
```

Comment: But when I update siteformFromPage, the siteForm won't update too

Comment: I've updated with a second solution, would that work?

Comment: Yes this work, but see the top questions, there are a better solutions with bind or arrow function.

Answer (score 0):

Use an arrow function to retain context:

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', (marker, siteForm) => {
    let newlatLng = marker.latLng; 
    console.log(this.siteForm);
  });
```

Comment: Can you explain me more about this  `=>` (arrow function) I'm new in Ionic 2

Comment: @CampDev This question has been marked as a duplicate. Check the top of the page to read more about how JavaScript handles the `this` keyword.